# How to access return type of a method from another method

Tags: java, class

I have the following code, where I have as input in the method a double number and 3 array lists of objects:

```
public static ArrayList<ELPERouteStop> relatedness(double pososto,ArrayList<ELPERouteStop> all_stops, ArrayList<Distance> distances, ArrayList<ELPEVehicleLoaded> vl_list)
{
//do stuff
return destroyedCustomers;
}
```

I need to call the list destroyedCustomers from another method of the same class.
The other class would be:

```
public void destroySolution(ArrayList<ELPERouteStop> removedCustomers, SolutionCreated sc,ArrayList<shadowVehicle> all_svehicles)
{
//do stuff
}
```

which I have as input the list of objects I need to access.
Is there any way I can have this access?
On my main method I have done the following:

```
LNS lns = new LNS();
lns.destroySolution(LNS_Procedure.relatedness(0.15,all_route_stops, distances, vl_list), sc, all_svehicles);
```

Is this going to work?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Do you have any reason to doubt it will work?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on what you're asking. If this is a generic case of method `a` calling the result of method `b`, then `a(b());` will return what you want, as expected. Is there anything different in your situation?

Comment: I believe that will work as you're stating. I was wondering (as I am not a developer) if this is ok, concerning access. Thank you again

Comment: A method can access what is passed to it as parameters - it doesn't matter where it comes from. If the two methods are in the same class as in your example, there cannot be any visibility issues. Related reading on what methods can and cannot do to their parameters in Java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see this is a generic case of method `a` calling method `b`. Since Java (and most languages) evaluate from the innermost statements to the outerwards ones, it definitely work as you'd expect:

```
a(b()); // Function composition, produces the result of applying a to the result of b
```

Java also passes references by value, which means any changes in the callee method (except reassignment) will be visible to the caller. In this case, if `b()` returns a list and `a()` adds an element to that list and returns it, whatever calls method `a` will see the extra element.